# Name for percent "distance" of the "length" of interval?

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have an interval $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$ (where $x_{min} \gt x_{max}$) and a quantity $x$ that is a member of this interval. Is there a name for the following quantity?

$\frac{x - x_{min}}{x_{max} - x_{min}}$

The best way I can describe this is as the ratio of $x$'s "distance" from the minimum to the "length" of the interval. When $x = x_{min}$, this is $0$, and it's $1$ when $x = x_{max}$.

Comment: When $x=x_{max}$, it's actually $-1$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Oh, pooh. Typos. Thanks. Fixing.

Comment: You could call it a linear ramp from $0$ to $1$ over $[x_\min,x_\max]$.

Comment: @Rahul I've never heard of a linear ramp. Do you have a source that could flush out what it is? I Googled, and not much came up.

Comment: If I don't get a clear answer, I might dub this the "relative interval position" (or r.i.p. XD) for lack of a better term.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd call that a *function*, say $f$, with domain $[a,b]$, $$f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

It is exactly the same thing if you place $x_{min}$ for $a$ and $x_{max}$ for $b$. And yes, it describes the ratio of the distances you're saying.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but by "a name for the quantity", I mean something terse to help me communicate with colleagues. =) Calling it a "function" is pretty vague and won't communicate what quantity I'm talking about very clearly. Granted, I might have to explain a more detailed term to them, but once I do, it's easy to refer to it. At the moment, about all I have is "percentage thing" (since in my actual usage, I'm multiplying by 100).

Comment: Ok, at least I make people laugh :D